# android - how can I know which editText was clicked in dialog fragment class

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I have two editText views, and when a user clicks the first editText, a dialogfragment window opens and the user selects the date. The same happens with the second editText. The date selected should be "written" in the editText.This works like a charm when I have one editText.  But how do I know which ediText was clicked, as they are in the same activity and I have to edit the editText in the dialogFragment class?

I have seen some other answers, but some of them are really outdated-deprecated, and some other didn 't help me.

Here is my code:

**Start class:**

```
public class Start extends FragmentActivity {

private EditText ddEdit;
private EditText adEdit;
int year;
int month;
int day;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        //i know this is not correct
    case R.id.etDepDate:
        DialogFragment depFragment = new DatePick();
        depFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker1");
        break;
    case R.id.etArrDate:
        DialogFragment arrFragment = new DatePick();
        arrFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker2");
        break;
    }

}
```

**DatePick class:**

```
  public class DatePick extends DialogFragment implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
private EditText ddEdit;
private EditText adEdit;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            String date = new String(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
         //????
         //how I know here which view was clicked so I can call the editTextById method?
        //??????



}

public void editTextById(View v, String date) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.etDepDate:
        setDate(date, ddEdit);
        setDate(date, adEdit);
        break;

    case R.id.etArrDate:
        setDate(date, adEdit);
        break;
    }
}

public void setDate(String date, EditText editText) {
    editText.setText(date);

}

@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.show(manager, tag);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the view when creating the dialog using newInstance(viewToBeEdited).
In the showDatePickerDialog modify your creation of the dialog in this way

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    depFragment = DatePick.newInstance(v);
    depFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker1");
    break;
}
```

Your DatePick Dialog must implement the static method newInstance(Viev v)

```
public class DatePick extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

   private EditText editableView;

   public static DatePick newInstance(View v) {
       DatePick dialog = new DatePick();
       dialog.editableView = v;
       return dialog;
   }

   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      <Your code>
   }

   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        final String date = new String(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
        getActivity().runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
            public run() {
                editableView.setText(date);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

I didn't test it, so there could be some typos, but this is typically what I do in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Put a flag for each edit text,and change the flag onclick()

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: do you know how to setup listeners??

Comment: i think that this is not the best way to do it